# How do you “add the declaration for SPDisposeCheckIgnore to your project?”

Tags: sharepoint, dispose

I have installed SPDispose and i am getting a number of false positives regarding

`SPWeb web = SPContext.Current.Web`;

I want to add  `[SPDisposeCheckIgnore(SPDisposeCheckID.SPDisposeCheckID_000, "Context Web does not need disposed.")]`

Answer (score 2):

You should decorate the method that contains the false positive with the `[SPDisposeCheckIgnore]` attribute:

```
[SPDisposeCheckIgnore(SPDisposeCheckID.SPDisposeCheckID_000,
    "Context Web does not need to be disposed.")]
public void YourMethod()
{
    SPWeb web = SPContext.Current.Web;
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, i also needed needed to write a class for the attribute and create my own class project to use it. All working now :)